# Tensor("StatefulPartitionedCall_8:0) and Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead exceptions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to use Elmo for word embedding with the downloaded imdb dataset. I found this example:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/03/learn-to-use-elmo-to-extract-features-from-text/

However, I am having different issues. The texts that I am processing are like the following:

```
20316    Simple story    why say more  It nails it s pr...
13180    It s cheesy  it s creepy  it s gross  but that...
23353    Astounding     This may have been A poor attem...
13658    In a penitentiary  four prisoners occupy a cel...
19625    An unusual take on time travel  instead of tra...
                       
24173    Is this your typical women in chains navy tran...
4522     I don t know much about Tobe Hooper  or why he...
1718     what kind of sh t is this  Power rangers vs Fr...
10006    I have a piece of advice for the people who ma...
12360    I went in not knowing anything about this movi...
Name: texts, Length: 24999, dtype: object
```

with a shape of (24999,)

```
elmo=hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2")
listTrain=[X_train[i:i+10] for i in range(0,X_train.shape[0],10)]
elmoTrain=[getElmo(elmo,i)for i in listTrain]
```

and my function getElmo is the following:

```
def getElmo(elmo,x):
    embed=elmo.signatures["default"](tf.constant(x)) 
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as ses: 
        ses.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
        ses.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer())
        return ses.run(tf.reduce_mean(embed,1))
```

The original source code of the link of the tutorial is the following:

```
def elmo_vectors(x):
  embeddings = elmo(x.tolist(), signature="default", as_dict=True)["elmo"]

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    # return average of ELMo features
    return sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(embeddings,1))
```

However, I have the following exceptions:

ValueError: Tensor("StatefulPartitionedCall_10:0", shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32)

and

TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.

How can I fix them?

Actually I am using Python 3.7 and tensorflow 2.3.